# Переезд к новому хостеру

Tags: домен, хостинг

Я впервые переезжаю на новый хостинг. На предыдущем хостинге был зарегистрирован домен. Что нужно, чтобы домен привязался к новому хостингу: только поменять запись А в панели управления доменом или что-то еще?

Answer (score 2):

Хостинг-провайдер это не регистратор в большинстве случаев. У хостинг-провайдера заключен договор с регистратором. Регистратор предоставляет API посредством которого Вы можете регистрировать и в последующем управлять своим доменом из панели управления хостинг-провайдера. Вы можете выполнить 2 вида переноса доменного имени:

**1. Технический перенос домена** - для этого необходимо указать NS сервера своего нового хостинг-провайдера в разделе управления записями DNS для домена в панели управления своего старого хостинг-провайдера. После этого необходимо разместить информацию о домене на NS серверах нового хостинг-провайдера, обычно эта процедура автоматизирована. Стоит отметить, что юридически домен остается на обслуживании у регистратора, с которым сотрудничает Ваш старый хостинг-провайдер, соответственно продлевать доменное имя прийдется тоже у него. Однако управлять DNS записями Вы сможете из панели управления нового хостинг-провайдера.

**2. Юридический перенос домена** - это перенос доменного имени к регистратору, с которым заключен договор у Вашего нового хостинг-провайдера.Для этого необходимо связаться с доменной службой старого хостинг-провайдера и узнать в какой форме необходимо написать заявление на перенос доменного имени на обслуживание к новому регистратору. После этого нужно написать заявлению новому регистратору о желании перенести доменное имени к ним на обслуживании. В этом случае оплачивать продление доменного имени Вы сможете уже через нового хостинг-провайдера.

**P.S.** Стоит отметить, что второй вариант хоть и сложнее, но предпочтительнее, т.к. избавит Вас от неприятностей в будущем.

Answer (score 1):

Домен зарегистрирован на вас? Если да, в DNS поменять A запись. Если нет, позаботиться о домене, и поменять запись, в принципе всё. )

Answer (score 1):

Если домен остается у хостера как у регистратора, то просто поменять запись типа А, так чтобы она указывала на ip нового сервера. А если домен переносится к другому регистратору, то еще поменять сервера имен.